# ZF2 Zend Logger - Filters by priority

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework2, verbosity

I'm using the Zend Logger with following configuration in the module_config.php:

```
'log' => [
    \Base\Log\ConsoleLoggerAwareInterface::class => [
        'writers' => [
            'standard-output' => [
                'name' => 'stream',
                'options' => [
                    'stream' => 'php://output',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

But as it is I can't influence the log to filter or suppress messages.
The goal is to improve the logging to be smarter.

I think I need to add a filter to the writer but I can't find an example how to do that in the module_config.php.

Is there also a way to call a script (e.g. from within a cron) by using a verbosity level?

I hope you know what I'm trying to achive.

**Edit:**

I have this example in my code:

```
$this->consoleLogger->emerg('EMERG');
$this->consoleLogger->alert('ALERT');
$this->consoleLogger->crit('CRIT');
$this->consoleLogger->err('ERR');
$this->consoleLogger->warn('WARN');
$this->consoleLogger->notice('NOTICE');
$this->consoleLogger->info('INFO');
$this->consoleLogger->debug('DEBUG');
```

Should it then not output the filtered ones?

Comment: I have this setting in application.ini, for example: resources.log.stdout.filterParams.priority = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: How to filter a Log Writer to a specific error level?**

Add a `filters` key to the particular writer's configuration. Here's direct instantiation to remove any configuration peculiarities: this outputs only "WARN" and "EMERG" messages:

```
$config = [
    'writers' => [
        'standard-output' => [
            'name' => 'stream',
            'options' => [
                'stream' => 'php://output',
                'filters' => \Zend\Log\Logger::WARN,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger($config);
$logger->emerg('EMERG');
$logger->warn('WARN');
$logger->debug('DEBUG');
```

Adding the `filters` configuration to your `modules_config.php` should have a similar effect. If not, check your zend-log version (with eg `composer show`) and advise.

---

**Q: How to change error level filter with the -v command line parameter?**

AFAIK, there is no automatic way to bind the standard verbose flag (`-v`) with a particular logging level. So you'll have to write your own filter. One thing that's neat to know is that the `filters` key can take:

- an `int` (as done above, which translates to the built-in log level);
- a `string` (corresponding to a class name implementing `\Zend\Log\Filter\FilterInterface`);
- an `object` (instance of `\Zend\Log\Filter\FilterInterface`);
- or an array of these.

You can use this flexibility to solve your need of binding a command line parameter to a log value. Here is a custom class that shows emergency events by default, but for every `v` on the command line increases the shown priority:

```
class CliLoggingFilter implements \Zend\Log\Filter\FilterInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->level = \Zend\Log\Logger::EMERG;
        if (array_key_exists('v', $args = getopt('v'))) {
            $this->level += count($args['v']);
        }
    }

    public function filter(array $event)
    {
        return ($event['priority'] <= $this->level);
    }
}
```

You'd then have a configuration like: `'filters' => CliLoggingFilter::class`.

```
$ php public/index.php
2016-07-25T10:57:28-04:00 EMERG (0): EMERG
$ php public/index.php -vvvv
2016-07-25T10:57:32-04:00 EMERG (0): EMERG
2016-07-25T10:57:32-04:00 WARN (4): WARN
$ php public/index.php -vvvvvvv
2016-07-25T10:57:34-04:00 EMERG (0): EMERG
2016-07-25T10:57:34-04:00 WARN (4): WARN
2016-07-25T10:57:34-04:00 DEBUG (7): DEBUG
```

---

**Q: How to change all routes to use -v?**

AFAIK, there is no way to specify a global command line parameter. You need to either (a) update all your console routes to accept the argument or (b) pass the log level a different way.

Updating all your routes isn't terribly hard. You can define a variable that holds the value and then include that in the configuration, like so:

```
$globalConsoleRouteParams = '[--verbose|-v]';
return [ 'console' => 'router' => 'routes' => [
    'foo' => [ 'options' => [ 'route' => "foo $globalConsoleRouteParams ..." ] ],
    'bar' => [ 'options' => [ 'route' => "bar $globalConsoleRouteParams ..." ] ],
    // ...
]];
```

Alternatively, you could use say environment variables to pass your desired log level, plus perhaps any additional configuration you might desire. Modifying our earlier example:

```
class CliLoggingFilter implements \Zend\Log\Filter\FilterInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->level = \Zend\Log\Logger::EMERG;
        if (false !== ($level = getenv('LOG_LEVEL'))) {
            $this->level = $level;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then it may be invoked like

```
$ LOG_LEVEL=7 php index.php foo
```

Comment: Yes, like php script.php -vvvv

Comment: Ok, AFAIK you'll need a custom class, example provided.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer, I'm about to implement the verbosity, but unfortunately, my console call doesn't expect -vvv parameters and says: "Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided"

Comment: How can I solve this without changing evey single console route?

Comment: Updated answer to include some approaches for solving this globally.

Comment: I built it with the ENV variable and it works! Thanks